# opencv resize + free kinect

Tags: opencv, image-resizing

I am trying to use opencv and freekinect library and I am building it with cmake in ubuntu 16 and there is no error or warning. But when I use resize function my code crashes. This is the part of the code that cause problem.

```
libfreenect2::Frame *rgb2 = frames2[libfreenect2::Frame::Color];
    libfreenect2::Frame *ir2 = frames2[libfreenect2::Frame::Ir];
    libfreenect2::Frame *depth2 = frames2[libfreenect2::Frame::Depth];


    //////////////////////to show 
        ///depth
        cv::Mat depthmat = cv::Mat(depth->height, depth->width, CV_32FC1, depth->data);
        cv::Mat depthmat2 = cv::Mat(depth2->height, depth2->width, CV_32FC1, depth2->data);

        //rgb
        cv::Mat RGBmat = cv::Mat(rgb->height, rgb->width, CV_8UC4, rgb->data);
        cv::Mat RGBmathalf =cv::Mat(rgb->height/2, rgb->width/2, CV_8UC4);
        cv::Mat RGBmat2 = cv::Mat(rgb2->height, rgb2->width, CV_8UC4, rgb2->data);
        //cv::resize(RGBmat, RGBmathalf, Size(512, 424),0,0,INTER_LINEAR);

    cv::imshow("depth_device1", depthmat );
        cv::imshow("depth_device2", depthmat2 );

        cv::imshow("RGB1", RGBmat );
        cv::imshow("RGB2", RGBmat2 );
```

Without resize function I can see the RGB stream but when I add the resize it crashes with the error of "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Use `imshow()` on everyone of those `RGB*` images to debug which image is not created correctly.

Comment: Actually, I can see all the images. But when I use resize it crashes. So the problem is not the data but the resize function

Comment: What is the size of `RGBmathalf`? Because you're passing `size(512,424)` as argument to `resize`.

Comment: In opencv documentation it is mentioned that it doesn't matter what is the size of the destination, however I tried  "cv::resize(RGBmat, RGBmathalf, RGBmathalf.Size,0,0,INTER_LINEAR);" and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I just got something else, When I resize any image in another project it works. Could it be somehow dependent on CmakeLists?

Comment: CMake has nothing to do with code execution, if it compiles correctly then it should run correctly. I am almost positive it has to do with arguments you pass to `resize`.

Comment: This seems to be the time for you to use the debugger.

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually test something else. When I open device then resize is not working and gives me this error. [Error] [VaapiRgbPacketProcessorImpl] vaDisplayIsValid(display) failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. I had a problem with VAAPI and nvidia gtx 1060 driver, since I have dual GPU. I just uninstall the default driver of nvidia and install the one mentioned here https://askubuntu.com/a/836504 and uninstall VAAPI. Now, it is working fine. Thank you so much for all the helps.